# Content displayed in a WebView on 4k screen seems to be very low resoultion

Tags: android, android-webview, android-tv

I'm displaying websites in a `WebView` on an `Android TV`. The device is 4k, but the Android is running in `1080p` (and that is OK) BUT the *WebView* seems to render in a `half-HD 540x960` (as reported by JavaScript window.screen.availHeight) - images and fonts look blurry.

This seems to match-up with density settings of a device `metrics.density = 2`. Is there a way to force full-resolution rendering in the app or the *WebView* itself?

Comment: Any fixes for this? I have an app in 1080p, with fixed UI and I do not want to change my UI to fit 960x540. Is there a way to allow 720p or 1080p in Android TV WebView?

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html#4K-display), The platform now allows apps to request that the display resolution be upgraded to 4K only for the compatible hardware.

> To query the current physical resolution, you need to use the [`Display.Mode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.Mode.html) APIs. If the UI is drawn at a lower logical resolution and is upscale to a larger physical resolution, be aware that the physical resolution the [`getPhysicalWidth()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.Mode.html#getPhysicalWidth()) method returns may differ from the logical resolution reported by [`getSize()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize(android.graphics.Point)).

So what you need to do is to change the physical resolution by setting the [`preferredDisplayModeId`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#preferredDisplayModeId) property of your app’s window.

Comment: Is there something that can be done on the older api levels? YouTube and Google Cast seems to use 4k.